# Any way to get past the load more button on webpages while scraping in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using the HtmlAgilityPack to locate the tags I need to scrape and get all the textual data from but I cannot figure out a way to get past the " Load More " button here's what I've tried so far from a tutorial any ideas would be appreciated.

```
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

    var Review = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
        .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "notfound").Equals("content")).ToList();

    foreach (var item in Review)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim().ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Well you might want to have a look in network panel what happens when page initially loads and when this "Load more" button is called. This will hopefully show some XHR request fetching more data from the server. That will already be a good start to actually fetch the data directly friom there rather than scraping the page

Comment: im kind of new to web scraping can you point me towards something that'll help me do this ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: Before you can scrape correctly you need to understand exactly what's going on. There are many articles out there explaining how the web works, and for practical examples you can pretty much learn a lot from the "Network" panel of our browser's developer tools.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion i looked into XHR and figured out a way to make it work for me , ill post the code if it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the " Load More " button was making  XHR requests to the server , the request had a dynamic pagination key attached to it every time a new call was made , so what i did was
collect all the urls(the requests) which contained the extended part of the reviews .
then scrape each url indiviually to retrieve what i wanted.

the function takes the url of the User reviews page as an argument
first 3 lines inside the function is to form the XHR request url , then the pagination key is retrieved from the html page and the url for the next page is formed , this goes on recursively untill all urls are found.

```
public async void GetUrls(string u)
{
    string toappend = "/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=";
    string aurl = u.Substring(0, 44) + toappend;
    var init_url = u;

    var httpCli = new HttpClient();
    var html = await httpCli.GetStringAsync(init_url);
    var htmldoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmldoc.LoadHtml(html);


    var nxt_url = htmldoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("loadmoredata")).ToList();

    if (nxt_url.Count!=0)
    {
        foreach (var item in nxt_url)
        {
            string url = item.GetAttributeValue("data-key", "").ToString();
            urllist.Add(url);
            string succ_url = aurl + url;
            //Console.WriteLine(succ_url);
            GetUrls(succ_url);
            Console.WriteLine("----Saving URLs..-----");
        }
    }
    else if(nxt_url.Count==0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Crawl Successful ");
        ScrapenSave(u);
    }
}
```